# How to get a raw error object on the try/catch instead of its stack

Tags: javascript, try-catch

I'm trying to understand how I can get the raw object of the error in the try/catch block like so:

```
try {
  
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

The above is logging the stack instead of the raw object.

I'm asking this out of curiosity, because at first, I tried to print the message and not the stack and only by searching the web I could find `this` object has property of `message`.

Answer (score 0):

There is `error.stack` which show the stack of error in string